# How to terminate collection Iterations in postman if test fails

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using postman for API's automation. Created collection runner and while execution, I provided Iterations as 5. I am trying to stop the whole test if any scenario fails.

I tried with the below options. But the current test is failing but it's going to the next iteration. How can I stop whole iterations?

- postman.setNextRequest(null);
- throw new Error('halt')

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can use `postman.setNextRequest(null)` and do something like this in your test:

```
// I used 500 status code for stopping condition
if(pm.response.code === 500) {
    postman.setNextRequest(null)
}
```